# Git bash extensions in different hard disk won't recognize npm

Tags: node.js, git, bash, npm

I've been trying to run node.js from the Git Bash, however my workspace is located in the second hard drive, every time I run node from C: it works ok but once I try to run it from D: says

```
Program Files\nodejs/node: No such file or directory
```

I tried with this line but didn't work

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:"C:Program Files\nodejs"
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested I fixed it by using this line

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/nodejs
```

without "", anybody know why?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the quotes, probably rather with the slashes. You should use / when inside the gitbash, not \ . If you use \, you should probably use \\ instead